# Php code to update or insert values

Tags: php, mysql, api

I am trying to write an API with php which will check the values a user has entered and if the  trackid and userid are already in the database it will update the rating. However if the track and user id doesn't exist then the API should insert them along with a rating. How can this be done. Please note I keep getting the error:

> Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object

on line 14. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['TrackId'];
$user = $_GET['UserId'];
$rating = $_GET['Rating'];

include("connect.php");
$query = "UPDATE `rating` SET `rating` = '$rating' WHERE track_id = '$id' AND user_id = '$user' AND rating_set=NOW()";
$sth = $dbc->query($query);
$rows = $sth->rowCount(); 

if ($rows != 2) {
$query = "INSERT INTO `rating` values ('$id','$rating','$user',NOW())";
$results = $dbc->query($query); 
$rows = $results->rowCount(); 
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo $_GET['onJSONPLoad'];
echo "(" . json_encode($rows) . ")";
 }
 else 
 {
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo $_GET['onJSONPLoad'];
echo "(" . json_encode($rows) . ")";
 }  

 $dbc = null;
 ?>
```

Comment: *sidenote:* your code is subjected to SQL Injection attack, as you directly allow GET values to be inserted in your query.

Comment: rather try to get `affected_rows`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the update query part of the condition I am looking for is NOW() which will never be found. So I moved it to the update section of the query instead of the conditional area.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because your `$results` is null / false, which is probably due to a failed SQL execution.

Assuming that your `$dbc->query($sql)` is a wrapper of [mysqli_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), the function will return `false` on failed query. To debug this behavior, you can `var_dump($results)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ON DUPLICATE KEY clause

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, ... ) 
    VALUES (’value1’, ...) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY
      UPDATE column2 = =value2, ...
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html